# Get timestamp from year

Tags: php

Is it possible to retrieve the timestamp through `strtotime()` with only the year as a parameter?

```
<?php
$ts = strtotime('2008', time());
echo date('Y', $ts);
```

this echos `2015` which is why I'm asking.

Comment: same result without the time() parameter in strtotime()

Comment: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ts)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very nice function to do this when you have one or more parts of a date you want to convert it to a timestamp called [mktime](http://php.net/mktime).

The arguments are *very* easy, and you don't have to concatenate strings to parse them afterwards:

```
int mktime ([ int $hour = date("H") [, int $minute = date("i") [, int $second = date("s") [, int $month = date("n") [, int $day = date("j") [, int $year = date("Y") [, int $is_dst = -1 ]]]]]]] )
```

so your code could be:

```
function nowInYear($year){
     return mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2014);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
function getTimestamp ($year) {
  return strtotime("01/01/$year");
}
```

This function retrieves the timestamp for the particular year. Note that, timestamp ranges from:

```
strtotime("01/01/$year")
strtotime("31/12/$year")
```

If you need the current time, but only the year changes, then you can construct using the `date()` object. You need to use OO PHP for this and it works only from `5.3.0`:

```
<?php
  $date = new DateTime();
  $date->setDate(2008, 01, 01);
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, may be:

```
function nowInYear($year){
     return mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2014);
}
```